# What does python interpreter do when you use Process or Pool to achieve multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

What does python interpreter do when you use Process or Pool to achieve multiprocessing. Are all the codes and global variables created copied to the child process?

Comment: Yes, they are copied. Theoretically, depending on the OS, you could have copy-on-write behavior, but in Python, it is almost impossible not to write since CPython uses reference counting, so just assigning a value will cause the copy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Operating System and on the start method you choose.

You can find a description of start methods in the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

Unix Operating Systems generally support all three methods whereas NT Operating Systems (Windows) only support the `spawn` method.